# What is the difference between Spark executor states Exited vs Killed?

Tags: apache-spark

I`m working with spark 1.2.1.
When I run spark jobs sometimes I get executor state "Exited" and sometimes "Killed", in both scenarios the job is finished successfully and  I invoking **SparkContext.stop()**...

I failed to understand the meaning of those states.

[image]

[image]

What is the difference between Spark executor states Exited vs Killed?

Comment: Are you invoking SparkContext.stop() at the end of your job?

Comment: @Sumit- yes, I invoking SparkContext.stop().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exited** - It means that the Executor finished the processing and it exists cleanly without any errors or exception.

**Killed** - It means that that executor is killed by an the Worker who stopped and asked to kill the executor. This situation can be because of many reasons like by some user driven action or may be your executor finished processing but due to some reason it does not exists but worker is exiting so it needs to Kill the executor.

Also as a good practice we should invoke `SparkContext.stop()` method at the end of Job. Though this would not ensure that you will always have "Exited" status but it will definitely ensure that cleanup is executed and resources are de-allocated.

Comment: @Sumit- where can I see what is the reason of "killed" worker? There is no errors in the log of the worker...

Comment: Killed does not mean an error/ exception. Assume It is something like "kill -9 <PID>". You will not see any errors in the logs.

Comment: So there is no way to know why the worker had killed?

Comment: As per the code it generates an `InterruptedException` which just have and info message logged. see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.2.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/worker/ExecutorRunner.scala#L156)